# Props not loaded on initial render from redux store

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to reactjs and need some help.

thanks for taking the time to solve my issue.

I am trying to get the data from props after authenticating a user from  Signin page .

so when I get to home page the props does not give me the data in "auth" on initial render but automatically renders again and gives me the data.

I need the data on initial render or else the page crashes due to user data in the home page not being present

**signin.js**

```
class Signin extends Component {




state = { isSignedIn: false,
user: [] }


uiConfig = {
signInFlow: "popup",
signInOptions: [
  firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
],
callbacks: {
  signInSuccess: () => false
}
}


componentDidMount = () => {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user,
  user})
  console.log("state user is", this.state.user)
  console.log("user on firebase", user)
})
}





render(){
  const { authError, auth } = this.props;

   if (auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/home' /> 
const signingin =  (
    this.state.isSignedIn ? (  
   <span>
   <h1>signedin</h1>
    </span> 

  ) : (
    <StyledFirebaseAuth
      uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
      firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} 
    />
  ))`


    return (
<div>{signingin}

</div>
    )
}

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return{
authError: state.auth.authError,
auth: state.firebase.auth
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
signIn: (creds) => dispatch(signIn(creds)),
signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signin);
```

**authActions.js**

```
export const signIn = (credentials) => {
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();

  firebase.auth()(
    credentials.email,
    credentials.password
  ).then(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' });
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', err });
  });

}
}

export const signOut = () => {
return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
  const firebase = getFirebase();

  firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS' })
  });
}
}
```

**authReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
authError: null
}

const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
  case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
    console.log('login error');
    return {
      ...state,
      authError: 'Login failed'
    }

  case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
    console.log('login success');
    return {
      ...state,
      authError: null
    }

  case 'SIGNOUT_SUCCESS':
    console.log('signout success');
    return state;


  default:
    return state
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { signOut } from './../store/actions/authActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'





class Home extends Component {


render(){



console.log( "the props here in home.js", this.props)



        return (
            <div>

        <h1> Welcome home</h1>
        <button onClick={() => { firebase.auth().signOut();}}>Sign out!</button>
              {/* <h1>Welcome {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}</h1> */}
              {/* <img
                alt="profile picture"
                src={firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL}
              /> */}
              </div>
        );



}
}

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return{
          auth: state.firebase.auth
        }
       }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {

          signOut: () => dispatch(signOut())
        }
      }


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

so in chrome developer tools when I am trying to print the props in console
it gives auth as `{isLoaded: false, isEmpty: true}`

Comment: so once signed in, you need the data. you can add one more check like once the  data is there then load the component still that time you can load a Loader or spinner which makes end user to think that some thing is loading.

Comment: can you please explain how i do that? really sorry I am new to this

Comment: sure will update the answer and let you know, i have some doubts in user which is in state are you holding the data of the user. Is that is your base of the application that makes the application without crashing

Comment: can you expalin the workflow also, like if uid is there it should redirect then if some error occurs you need to show error, if uid is  there show user is signed in and show him the ui like that.  It will be helpful to answer the question with all condtion checking

Comment: the user data is coming from Google authentication. if uid is there then it should redirect to home page so that login page is not available, since the presence of auth.uid shows the user is logged in.